# Getting the root device in a kernel module

Tags: linux, kernel-module

I did some web searches for this, but could only find results about getting the kernel module associated with a device node. Is there anyway I can get the major and minor numbers of the current system's root device and, if applicable, the root device's parent device (e.g., `/dev/sda` is the "parent" of `/dev/sda2`)? Does the kernel export some functions for getting this or would I need to get it indirectly?

Answer (score 0):

There is no module associated with a device node.  Possibly you know that the root directory is something local to a process (the process structure stores the inode reference for the root directory --- and this can be changed with the privileged `chroot(2)` system call) and the current working directory (to solve for paths not beginning with `/`)

If you want to know the device responsible of the root directory you have two options:

- Your process has not been made a `chroot(2)` syscall, so you `opendir("/")` and then do a `fstat(2)` on it (or you can do a `stat(2)` syscall on the `"/"` directory).  This will give the device in which the root directory resides as the `st_dev` field of the `struct stat` returns.  It is formatted as a `dev_t` number, in which some of the bits represent the major number and some the minor number.  You can use the `MKDEV(ma,mi)` and `MAJOR(dev)` and `MINOR(dev)` macros defined in `<linux/kdev_t.h>` to access the major and minor numbers.  To get the physical disk, just mask the minor number with `0xf0` and you will get the minor number of the whole disk.
- your process has made a `chroot(2)` syscall, so you are not allowed to access the real root directory in the system.  If you have access to the `/proc` filesystem, then probably you can call `mount(1)` command to get the mount table.  you can search that table for the `/` entry, and then get the `/dev/sd<disk>` entry.  Once you got the device, getting the parent device is easy.  You can mask the number as you did in the last point to get the minor number of the physical disk.

You can also get to the `/proc/diskstats` file, that shows you the statistics of each block device.  You'll get the major, minor and device name in the first three fields of each line.

## NOTE

There are some disk arrangementes that dont't allow partitioning, as RAID devices or volume manager disks.  In those cases, getting to the physical disk (or disks, as there can be more than one) is more difficult.

Comment: This doesn't answer my question.